# How to disable TensorBoard Image viewer pagination

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I usualy use `tf.summary.image()` to monitor generated images on learning.

- 8(or more) input images
- 8(or more) generated images
- 8(or more) ground truth images

With opening TensorBoard Images tab, opening all pane, setting browser zoom 50%, I can view all images in one window.

Yesterday, I tried latest TensorBoard. Images tab view's pagination prevents to view all images at once.

Can I disable pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from TensorBoard 0.4, I can set images per page value from settings dialog.